# update and existing excel file via outlook mail with excel file attachment

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I currently have this next code in outlook VBA(found it in one of the topics here):

```
Public Sub FMK(Item As Outlook.MailItem)

Const PathName = "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\files\Diary.xlsx"

Dim arrLines As Variant
Dim varLines As Variant
Dim RowNext As Long
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim ExcelWkBk As Excel.Workbook
Dim excWkb As Object
Dim excWks As Object
Dim temp As String

arrLines = Split(Item.Body, vbCrLf)

Set xlApp = Application.CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set excWkb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(PathName)
Set excWks = excWkb.ActiveSheet


RowNext = excWks.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row + 1
With excWks
excWks.Cells(RowNext, 1) = temp
End With
RowNext = RowNext + 1

excWkb.SaveAs PathName
excWkb.Close

End Sub
```

Please help me ...
I need to update an Excel file that exists on my computer using a file that comes in Outlook ...
Always the same format files
I just want to add the lines that come Excel files by e-mail in addition to what is in the file on your PC
My knowledge is very limited in VBA

Answer (score 0):

You can automate Outlook from Excel for extracting the required attached file. The Attachment class provides the SaveAs method which can be used to save the file on the disk. Then you can use the Open method of the Workbook class to open the just saved file.

See [How to automate Outlook from another program](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/201096?wa=wsignin1.0) for more information.

Comment: Also you may find the [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736%28v=office.14%29.aspx) article.